# Postgresql shutdown by itself

Tags: postgresql

```
2021-11-03 07:15:23.704 UTC [354507] postgres@postgres FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
2021-11-03 07:15:23.704 UTC [354507] postgres@postgres DETAIL:  Password does not match for user "postgres".
    Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 105: "host    all         all         0.0.0.0/0       md5"
2021-11-03 07:33:29.904 UTC [354788] pgsql@postgres FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "pgsql"
2021-11-03 07:33:29.904 UTC [354788] pgsql@postgres DETAIL:  Role "pgsql" does not exist.
    Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 105: "host    all         all         0.0.0.0/0       md5"
2021-11-03 07:52:40.628 UTC [355083] pgsql@postgres FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "pgsql"
2021-11-03 07:52:40.628 UTC [355083] pgsql@postgres DETAIL:  Role "pgsql" does not exist.
    Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 105: "host    all         all         0.0.0.0/0       md5"
2021-11-03 07:53:02.963 UTC [327839] LOG:  received smart shutdown request
2021-11-03 07:53:02.976 UTC [327839] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 327846) exited with exit code 1
2021-11-03 07:53:02.980 UTC [327841] LOG:  shutting down
2021-11-03 07:53:03.011 UTC [327839] LOG:  database system is shut down
```

I am hosting PostgreSQL on a DigitalOcean droplet and since this server is just for my toy project only so I have all the ports open. I understand this is bad practice but from my understanding, unless the hacker somehow gains access to my username and password the DB will be safe.

But last month and yesterday my Postgre just shut down itself and according to the log, it seems it was shut down after a shutdown request?

I am using "postgres" as my user name and from the log, I can see someone keep trying to log with the username "pgsql"?

So I want to know am I being hacked or I did something stupid and somehow shut down the server by myself?

Comment: from postgresql manual here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/server-shutdown.html it says that ```received smart shutdown request``` is the result of sending ```SIGTERM``` to postgres process, so you might want to investigate why such signal is sent (e.g.: by ```kill/pkill``` command, by system shutdown, etc)

Comment: @Kristian Thank you for pointing me to the right direction. From auth.log I can see someone is getting access to my server and might have killed my postgresql!

Comment: This question might better fit to ServerFault forum.